# Command not found

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator, qmake

When I try to build my Qt project in QtCreator I get this error:

```
:-1: error: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++: Command not found
```

Can't figure out why I get this because it's in my PATH and I also use it as compiler in my project settings.

Comment: Is the PATH correctly imported to QtCreator Project Envirionment? Is the compiler set up with absolute path in QtCreator Settings?

Comment: How Can I check PATH in QtCreator? About compiler: yes, I use absolute path.

Comment: Open your Project, choose "Project" from the left sidemenu, and take a look at Build Environment within tab Build-Settings

Comment: Does it work if you build from command line? What build system does your project use, and exactly which Qt SDK (libs + tools)?

Comment: Link to a solution which might help you: http://www.friendlyarm.net/forum/topic/2291#10903 . And if it helps you solve it, write an answer to your own question to tell what you did exactly, please!

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @hyde, I can build project from console. I use Qt 4.8.5 with CodeSourcery Toolchain for ARM processors. OS: Ubuntu 13.10 x86_64

Comment: @SebastianLange, I looked at Build Environment settings, there's path to my toolchain binaries in PATH variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use CodeSourcery Toolchain and when I installed it, it added this line to my `.bash_profile`: `PATH="/home/dmitry/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin:${PATH}"`.

But in QtCreator's PATH variable there was a little bit different value: `/home/dmitry/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi`. In this directory there are files with short names like `g++` etc. So I just added the path from `.bash_profile` and now I am able to build the project.

Comment: OK, so basically what was written, you have messed the path up. ^^ Glad it works now.

Comment: Thanks. I thought QtCreator used the same environment variables I used in console. That's what confused me.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because I was using the 32 bit Code Sourcery compiler without the corresponding 32 bit linker on my 64 bit Debian Wheezy. The issue was fixed by simple installing the 32 bit toolchain, including the ld linker. Without that, the command does not quite appear as an executable.

You are trying to cross-compile on a 64 bit machine for 32 bit, so you need to have the 32 bit toolchain files available in the proper path, too.

Why it works without QtCreator, that is mysterious, but probably because you already have it installed, but the path and/or the mkspec specific in QtCreator is not right for 32 bit.

Comment: I have `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld` in the same path with `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++` if that's what you mean.

Comment: @DmitryMikhaylov: I meant the ld supplied by the package `libc6-i386` or something like that. This is the package name on my Debian Wheezy. Run `ldd -r /path/to/the/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++

Answer (score -1):

Using this long thing, arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++, is improbable although not impossible.

I suggest to create a wrapper for this name to your original compiler (probably like arm-...-gcc or simply gcc).

Comment: Why? It's a cross compiler, the name should say exactly which one, as often there are many similar toolchains installed.

Comment: @hyde It is too long. I suspect it is some autogenerated name, and not the exact name of his crosscompiler (whivh is probably some like arm-...-gcc).

Comment: No, that is perfectly normal, standard name for that particular compiler binary.

Comment: @hyde I didn't said it weren't normal, I said it is unusual long, and thus it is coming probably not from his distro, but was autogenerated by some tool.

Comment: I remember a similar problem, but it was not the compiler-path the problem, but the targetpath was to long. Changing build directory to D:\testbuild solved the problem

Comment: @SebastianLange Indeed, bumping into too long paths (or maybe it is too long total command line length, not sure...) is not uncommon under Windows with Qt. There are several different limits I think, and something commonly done by (maybe) *qmake* will easily trigger some of these limits, usually solved by moving the working directory closer to root, but sometimes requiring project restructuring (probably good anyway if dir structure is that deep). But is this question about Windows?

Comment: @PeterHorvath Be as it may, I think this answer gives wrong advice. There's no point or need to create wrappers for binaries in common toolchains. But if you can back up your suggestion somehow, please do!

Comment: @hyde Bugfix or handling incompatibility in the dev. environment  may be a point, if there is no better way, although it didn't happen on a well-integrated development environment. And I used no wrapper, but symlinks.

Comment: @PeterHorvath SO answers should be a bit more substantial. For "things you can try", a comment is better. The compiler for the toolchain is configured somewhere depending on exact build system, and just trying different names for compiler binary is not going to be useful without more exact instructions.

Comment: I agree with @hyde in here. "Too long" cannot be an issue, especially if it is installed properly into the system path by the corresponding ubuntu packages, which should be the case anyhow. I would personally remove this answer not the posterity. There is nothing wrong about the created toolchain after all. It is a standard CS toolchain used by many embedded developers, including us.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Maybe you should check, what is the name of the arm cross-compiler in ubuntu. The relevant package is here: http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-4.6-armel-cross/gcc-4.6-arm-linux-gnueabi_4.6.3-1ubuntu5cross1.62_amd64.deb Here you can see, that the name of the arm crosscompiler in ubuntu is arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc, and not arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc , which qtCreator tries to use.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: as far as I can tell, that is a different toolchain, and not from Code Sourcery. The OP was using code sourcery. Even if it was, it is still not related to long binary names and paths. The OP seems to have just messed up the PATH. :-)

Comment: @hyde See my previous comment, it may be useful also for you.

Comment: @LaszloPapp And exactly this toolchain difference can explain the difference between the names of the cross-compilers.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: I am not sure how that would happen. It seems that the issue has been that the OP used a different path. If you check out the Code Sourcery toolchain at some point, you will see that it has "long" and "short" binary names, too. That caused the confusion for the OP as I see. I have been using the Code Sourcery toolchain for a bit less than a year (I wish I did not) and it is possible to configure QtCreator properly.